# Set Join in SearchCriteria select

Tags: magento2, search-criteria, webapi

I need to override the get orders list API call, and set a join with my custom table, but without loose the SearchCriteria terms, is this possible?

Current Code:
(I've created a plugin in `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` inside webapi_rest folder.)

```
public function aroundGetList
(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
    callable $proceed,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
){
    $searchResult = $this->searchResultFactory->create();
    $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $searchResult);
    $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
    foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $order) {
        $this->setShippingAssignments($order);
    }
    return $searchResult;

}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I solve this situation as following:

```
$searchResult->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('my_table'=>'myAlias'),
        'main_table.entity_id = myAlias.id',
        []
    );
```

Comment: their is no getSelect() method in SearchResult